# Xamarin Android. Breakpoints don't work in PCL, but work in Android Project

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Breakpoints don't work in PCL project, while I am debugging Android project on emulator and on real device.

Project includes Mvvmcross. PCL contains ViewModels. Android project and iOS project contains views and some native logic. Breakpoint don't work in ViewModel, while I am debugging Android project. Breakpoints work in Android activity classes. When I debugging iOS project, breakpoints work in ViewModel and classes from iOS project.

I have reinstalled OS X, Visual Studio and restored all packages in project. I have tried this project on another Mac and breakpoints in PCL for Android don't work.

If I debug some Xamarin example project, breakpoints work in PCL and Android project. 
I am using Visual Studio for Mac(Version 7.0.1).

Comment: Make sure that your build configuration includes the PCL project to `Build`

Comment: @JonDouglas yes, build configuration includes The PCL project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same trouble with breakpoints.

Check ur android project settings:

[image: First option]

[image: Second option]

It works for me.